# System.Windows.Input.Icommand in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, binding

i have got the following in the xaml:

```
        <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxButton1"
        Margin="10,0,10,10"
        Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Enter Text"
        Controls:TextboxHelper.ButtonCommand="{Binding BrowseFileAction}"
        Style="{StaticResource OpenFilTextBox}"
        />
```

In the powershell code i need to set "BrowseFileAction" to perform the following action: browse for file.

Basically i would like to know how to convert the following c# code to powershell:

```
private string selectedPath = string.Empty;

public string SelectedPath
{
    get { return this.selectedPath; }
    set { this.SetProperty<string>(ref this.selectedPath, value); }
}

public ICommand BrowseFileCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(BrowseFileAction); }
}

public void BrowseFileAction()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if ((result.HasValue) && (result.Value))
    {
        this.SelectedPath = dialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Source - http://cisart.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/metro-textbox-with-browse-folder-button-and-validation/comment-page-1/

i tried to do this using add-type but powershell complained about missing class,delegate or interface..
I am sure this has to do something with the c# syntax but i dont know c# so not able to modify the code for add-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `namespace` and `class` declarations around that code e.g. you need:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class FileAction {
        private string selectedPath = string.Empty;
        ... rest of your code here ...
    }
}
```

However you are also missing the definition of the RelayCommand type.  Here's an [article that shows to implement RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051).  Finally, somewhere you need to set the XAML Window's DataContext property to an instance of FileAction.

Comment: thanks for the reply Keith.. i looked at the link you provided for relaycommand but seems too much c# for me to wrap my head around :)...is it possible to avoid using any of the c# code and maybe use some constructor of the kind of a constructor in powershell eg: new-object system.windows.input.icommand

Comment: You can't instantiate interfaces.  You can instantiate an instance of a class that implements an interface.  RelayCommand implements the ICommand interface.  Also, in PowerShell you will not be able to implement classes that implement an interface.  You will need C# for that.  Perhaps you should look at a PowerShell WPF module like ShowUI that does much of this work for you?  http://showui.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks that cleared things up :)...the problem with showui is that it needs to be on whichever computer that executes the code and also showui isnt all that simple...I ended up putting the textbox and a button in a stackpanel which kind of mimics the behaviour i wanted..yes it does mask the typed text a tiny bit but i think i can live with it and so will whoever is going to use it lol...